# Сохранение скина игрока после перезапуска игры

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть метод который считывает выбор игрока и выбирает скин (который выбрал игрок)
Мне нужно чтобы после выхода из игры программа записывала выбор игрока и при запуске изменяла скин.

Проблема в том что код у меня уже есть , но я уже второй день не могу найти ошибку .
Код:

```
  int Memory;
    void Start 
     {
     Memory = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("PlayerDecision");
      ChangeSkin(Memory);
    }


public void ChangeSkin(int Skins)
    {
        switch (Skins)
        {         
            case 1:
                if (MoneyShop >= 10)
                {
//Изменяем скин 
                    GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = Sprite1;
//Записываем выбор игрока в память 
                    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("PlayerDecision",1);
                }
                break;
         case 2:
                if (MoneyShop >= 10)
                {
//Изменяем скин 
                    GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = Sprite2;
//Записываем выбор игрока в память 
                    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("PlayerDecision",2);
                }
                break;
         case 3:
                if (MoneyShop >= 10)
                {
//Изменяем скин 
                    GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = Sprite3;
//Записываем выбор игрока в память 
                    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("PlayerDecision",3);
                }
                break;
           }
    }
```

Comment: Вы уверены, что при старте у Игрока имеется хотя бы 10 "MoneyShop"? ...Да и спрайт везде один Sprite1 - это тоже корректно?

Comment: @Александр Даниловский Со спрайтам я случайно ошибся когда выбирал нужный код для вопроса , а вот с проверкой на деньги я сейчас посмотрю .

Comment: @Александр Даниловский Да,из-за большого объема кода и своей невнимательности я сделал столь глупую ошибку . Я даже не знаю ,нужно ли оставлять вопрос (я не думаю что он будет полезен другим ).Думаю,стоит удалить .

Comment: Удаление вопроса - моветон. Лучше сами напишите ответ на собственный вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка оказалась очень простой:
Я не успел создать скрипт который сохраняет покупку игрока и получается что у игрока при перезапуске игры нету "денег" для "повторной покупки"(Скриптов для сохранение денег и покупок в проекте пока нету) для изменение скина.

```
      int Memory;
        void Start 
         {
         Memory = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("PlayerDecision");
          ChangeSkin(Memory);
        }


    public void ChangeSkin(int Skins)
        {
            switch (Skins)
            {         
                case 1:
//При заходе в игру у игрока MoneyShop = 0 и if `(MoneyShop >= 10)` не работает.
                    if (MoneyShop >= 10)
                    {
    //Изменяем скин 
                        GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = Sprite1;
    //Записываем выбор игрока в память 
                        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("PlayerDecision",1);
                    }
                    break;
             case 2:
//При заходе в игру у игрока MoneyShop = 0 и if `(MoneyShop >= 10)` не работает.
                    if (MoneyShop >= 10)
                    {
    //Изменяем скин 
                        GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = Sprite2;
    //Записываем выбор игрока в память 
                        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("PlayerDecision",2);
                    }
                    break;
             case 3:
//При заходе в игру у игрока MoneyShop = 0 и if `(MoneyShop >= 10)` не работает.
                    if (MoneyShop >= 10)
                    {
    //Изменяем скин 
                        GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = Sprite3;
    //Записываем выбор игрока в память 
                        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("PlayerDecision",3);
                    }
                    break;
               }
        }
```

Comment: сигнатуру метода `ChangeSkin` можно изменить на `ChangeSkin(int Skins, bool CheckMoney = true)`. А условия изменить на `if (MoneyShop >= 10 || !CheckMoney)`. В методе, где идет покупка, вызов `ChangeSkin` править не придется, т.к. есть значение аргумента по умолчанию, а при старте вызывайте так: `ChangeSkin(Memory, false)`

Comment: @АлександрДаниловский Если я делаю таким способ как вы мне сказали , то в On Click пропадает функция и я просто не могу её использовать.

Comment: Думаю , мне в такой способ не очень подходит .Нужно сделать запоминание покупки игрока и тогда потребность проверки при старте на деньги уже не будет нужна.